# How can I capitalize field text values at OnChange in MS CRM 2015?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, uppercase

I'm fairly new to CRM development and I'm trying to customize my account form to Capitalize any text field at onChange. I'm currently working with this function that I found online:

```
function UpperCaseField(fieldName)
{
var value = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).getValue();
if (value != null)
{
   Xrm.page,getAttribute(fieldName).setValue(value.toUpperCase());
}
}
```

However, when I change a value in my test account it tells me that the method getValue() is not supported. Everything I've found tells me to use getValue(). Im at a loss.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a getValue is not supported error, double check that the value for fieldName is actually a field on the form.  It's best to code more defensively, like this:

```
function UpperCaseField(fieldName)
{
    var attr = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName);
    if (!attr) { 
        console.log(fieldName + " not found"); 
        return; 
    }

    var value = attr.getValue();
    if (value != null)
    {
       attr.setValue(value.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Update: When you connect your fields to JS functions via the form editor, CRM passes an event context as the first parameter.  Here's what the code would look like in that case:

```
function UpperCaseField(context)
{
    var fieldName == context.getEventSource().getName();
    var attr = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName);
    if (!attr) { 
        console.log(fieldName + " not found"); 
        return; 
    }

    var value = attr.getValue();
    if (value != null)
    {
       attr.setValue(value.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Here's more info about the context: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328130.aspx

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer.

"double check that the value for fieldName is actually a field on the form"

What do you mean by this? I may be misunderstanding how the code works but do you mean that I have to place the name of the field I'm working with as the parameter for the function? I had assumed that by registering the function with the specific field onChange that fieldName would automatically take the field name of the field it's registered to. 

Either way, the code above gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace line

```
Xrm.page,getAttribute(fieldName).setValue(value.toUpperCase());
```

with line

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).setValue(value.toUpperCase());
```

Also please provide a screenshot that shows how you use/register this handler.